# Serilog custom sink - setting minimum level with appsettings.json not working

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I'm trying to write a custom Serilog sink, but I can't seem to get the "restrictedToMinimumLevel" arg to work. I believe my appsettings.json is correct, as the sink's emit method does run; however, the method runs for all log levels. What am I missing?

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Serilog":
    {
        "Using":
        [
            "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
            "CustomSerilogTest"
        ],
        "MinimumLevel":
        {
            "Default": "Debug"
        },
        "WriteTo":
        [
            {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args":
                {
                    "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message} {NewLine}{Exception}"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "MyCustomSink",
                "Args":
                {
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Custom Sink Class**

```
namespace CustomSerilogTest
{
    public class MyCustomSink : ILogEventSink
    {
        private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;

        public MyCustomSink(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            _formatProvider = formatProvider;
        }

        public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            //method fires, but is not limited to errors
            var message = logEvent.RenderMessage(_formatProvider);
        }
    }

    public static class SerilogExtensions
    {
        public static LoggerConfiguration MyCustomSink(
          this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
          IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
        {
            return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new MyCustomSink(formatProvider));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is works for me.  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "IsJson": true,
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:\\Logs\\Log-{Hour}.json",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ]
  },

Comment: As a note, the "restrictedToMinimumLevel" arg works for the Console, but not for my custom logger class.

Comment: Try moving "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error" out of the Args section. Sometimes that works. I believe it has to do with Custom Sink type.    "Name": "MyCustomSink",
                "Args":
                {
                   "CustomFlag":"CustomValue"
                }, "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, it is still emitting on all levels.

        "WriteTo":
        [
            {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args":
                {
                    "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message} {NewLine}{Exception}"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "MyCustomSink",
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
            }
        ]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It seems that you have to add a parameter in the extension method, like so:

```
public static class SerilogExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration MyCustomSink(
      this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
      LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LevelAlias.Minimum,
      IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
    {
        return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new MyCustomSink(formatProvider), restrictedToMinimumLevel: restrictedToMinimumLevel);
    }
}
```